# Insert a dropdownlist value into route values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a following controller:

```
public class StoreController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string category, int? page)
    {
      //some code
    }
}
```

and a view which posts data to the `Index` method:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Store", new { category = Model.Category, page = 1}))
 {
    <input type = "submit" class="btn btn-default" value = "Search" />
    @:Choose category: &emsp;
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "All", Value = "All", Selected = true},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Cat1", Value = "Cat1"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Cat2", Value = "Cat2"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "Cat3", Value = "Cat3"}
    })
 }
```

The problem is, the route value passed to the `Index` method is obviously wrong, since `Model.Category` is the Category of a Model passed to the view. I'm trying to route using the selected value from dropdown list. The question is how do I retrieve it?

I know I could just do it all with jquery Ajax but I wanna try it this way first. Is it possible to do it in a simple way or would I actually have to modify the GET request ?

Comment: Make the form `FormMethod.Get` and remove the `new { category = Model.Category }`. The selected value of the dropdown will then be added to the route values

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wanted to keep the code small so I didn't include the full form but actually it has other values which I want to POST, so GET is unacceptable. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: How many other values? If its likely to exceed the query string limit then just do a POST instead of a GET.

Comment: I know I could just post all values without routing but I don't like the ugly URL with the query string :) I want a URL like this: `/Store/Index/Cat1/1`

Comment: If you want a GET, then you need to include all the values in the route. If you don't want to put all the values in the route/query string, then you need to use a POST.

Answer (score 0):

your model should be something like

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Category {get; set;}
    public int? page {get; set;}
}
```

to use this

```
public class StoreController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
    {
        // process ur submit page with proper category
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      var model = new MyModel();
      model.Category = "All"; // the default category
      return View();
    }
}
```

render dropdown this way

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category, new[]
{
    new SelectListItem{ Text = "All", Value = "All" },  // YOU DO NOT NEED TO KEEP THIS SELECTED, MVC DOES AUTO SELECT BASED ON PROPERTY VALUE
    new SelectListItem{ Text = "Cat1", Value = "Cat1"},
    new SelectListItem{ Text = "Cat2", Value = "Cat2"},
    new SelectListItem{ Text = "Cat3", Value = "Cat3"}
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I wanted to keep the code small so I didn't include all details but actually my model has more values which I want to POST, and do the routing with just the two values mentioned in my original post. So I'm posting category, page and 5 other values, but I want my route to be like:

`/Store/Index/Cat1/1`